# Boot stuck at this screen

Tags: boot, kernel, kubuntu

[image]

This started after kernel update.
I've tried this boot option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

But it doesn't solve problem sometimes it doesn't work.

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, Kernel version: `4.15.0-52-generic`

Will performing boot repair help to get rid of this?

Comment: Does not look like a Boot Repair issue. Instead, try [rebooting into GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) and select an older kernel. Once you get a bootable system, reinstall the newer kernel and replicate the bug. If it still persists, file a bug aginst the `linux` package.

Comment: Thank you so much.